# How to configure web application in JProfiler?

Tags: java, jprofiler

I want to configure web application to JProfiler 7.1.2. Below are details which I carried out while configuring the session.

Web Server: Tomcat 5.0
Operating System: Windows XP

1. We have selected session type as "Web Start".
2. In Web Start settings section, How to select URL of JNLP file? 
   (we could not find out JNLP file).
3. Also we have selected Java VM as a "Oracle JRE 1.6.0_22".
4. We have configured Class Path.
5. After clicking OK after some time it shows application error as "Unable to launch application".

It shows error details as follows

```
CouldNotLoadArgumentException[ Could not load file/URL specified: D:\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.19\conf]
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

One more question, How can I add my project classes? I can not see project class file in Memory Views --> Agreegation Level --> Classes

Please guide me.
Awaiting reply

Answer (score 1):

"Java Web start" has nothing to do with web applications. To profile Tomcat, invoke

Session->Integration Wizards->New Server Integration

and follow the steps in the wizard.